# Java SIGSEGV exception in libjvm library (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76394088/ubuntu-minecraft-server-consistently-crashes) About a bug I encountered; apparently that wasn't the correct place to post.

Hopefully this is, I am unsure where to put this.

To recap, I am running a Minecraft server on Ubuntu, with the arguments `-Xms1024M -Xmx10G Minecraft_Server_1.20.jar nogui`, and I do not understand what is causing the crash. It crashes with a SIGSEGV error, presumably caused by something in libjvm, but I do not understand how to properly diagnose the issue

as of now,

- I tried updating to JDK 18 as another user suggested, it still crashes.
- I have tried fully reinstalling JDK & server, issue persists
- I have run a memory test, faulty memory was not an issue

If this is a bug in the JDK, could you please point me on how to report it or go about analyzing the issue? Also I tried to read the 'core dump' but I could not find the file, supposedly located at `/opt/minecraft/minecraftserver/antServer/core.551710`, yet there was no file starting with core? Help understanding these two issues would be greatly appreciated.

```
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd860f6c1b0, pid=551710, tid=551731
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (18.0.2+9) (build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-222.04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-222.04, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 3431 c2 dcd.a(Ldde;Ljava/lang/Comparable;)Ljava/lang/Object; (84 bytes) @ 0x00007fd860f6c1b0 [0x00007fd860f6bf00+0x00000000000002b0]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /opt/minecraft/minecraftserver/antServer/core.551710)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   Unknown
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Xms1024M -Xmx10G Minecraft_Server_1.20.jar nogui

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 4 cores, 62G, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Time: Sun Jun 11 21:57:47 2023 EDT elapsed time: 2.316663 seconds (0d 0h 0m 2s)
```

I can post the rest if necessary

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fd870198a90):  JavaThread "ServerMain" [_thread_in_Java, id=551731, stack(0x00007fd840d38000,0x00007fd840e38000)]

Stack: [0x00007fd840d38000,0x00007fd840e38000],  sp=0x00007fd840e35810,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 3431 c2 dcd.a(Ldde;Ljava/lang/Comparable;)Ljava/lang/Object; (84 bytes) @ 0x00007fd860f6c1b0 [0x00007fd860f6bf00+0x00000000000002b0]
j  csj.a(Ldcb;Lcls;Lgu;Leen;)Lefb;+12
J 3839 c2 dca$a.a(Lcls;Lgu;Leen;)Lefb; (15 bytes) @ 0x00007fd860fc8f1c [0x00007fd860fc8ea0+0x000000000000007c]
J 3684 c1 cpn.c(Ldcb;Lcls;Lgu;)Z (28 bytes) @ 0x00007fd859eaf47c [0x00007fd859eaf400+0x000000000000007c]
J 3784 c1 dca$a$a.<init>(Ldcb;)V (349 bytes) @ 0x00007fd859ee287c [0x00007fd859ee2760+0x000000000000011c]
J 3698 c1 dca$a.a()V (70 bytes) @ 0x00007fd859eb41f4 [0x00007fd859eb4000+0x00000000000001f4]
j  cpo.<clinit>()V+40026
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x8b7fca]
V  [libjvm.so+0x895d40]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8a8a8e]
V  [libjvm.so+0xab199e]
V  [libjvm.so+0xab21ae]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8bcef9]
j  csj.a()V+0
j  acs.a()V+41
j  net.minecraft.server.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+271
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH+0x0000000800d5d800.invokeStatic(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+10 java.base@18.0.2-ea
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x0000000800d63400.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+31 java.base@18.0.2-ea
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH+0x0000000800d63000.invoke_MT(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+18 java.base@18.0.2-ea
j  net.minecraft.bundler.Main.lambda$run$0(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/net/URLClassLoader;[Ljava/lang/String;)V+34
j  net.minecraft.bundler.Main$$Lambda$5+0x0000000800c02228.run()V+12
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 java.base@18.0.2-ea
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x8b7fca]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8b8675]
V  [libjvm.so+0x99db31]
V  [libjvm.so+0xd9a5b3]
V  [libjvm.so+0xbd84ac]



siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: 0x00000005ff86f518

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x00007fd8291d6048} 'equals' '(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z' in 'ddb'
RCX=2954328978 is a compressed pointer to object: [Lcom.google.common.collect.ImmutableMapEntry;
{0x0000000580bbdc90} - klass: 'com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMapEntry'[]
 - length: 8
RDX=0x0000000582a1a788 is an oop: ddb
{0x0000000582a1a788} - klass: 'ddb'
 - ---- fields (total size 6 words):
 - private final 'a' 'Ljava/lang/Class;' @12  a 'java/lang/Class'{0x00000007ff701a98} = 'java/lang/Integer' (ffee0353)
 - private final 'b' 'Ljava/lang/String;' @16  "age"{0x0000000582ad36b0} (b055a6d6)
 - private 'c' 'Ljava/lang/Integer;' @20  a 'java/lang/Integer'{0x00000005841a8d60} = 1101196024 (b08351ac)
 - private final 'd' 'Lcom/mojang/serialization/Codec;' @24  a 'com/mojang/serialization/Codec$2'{0x0000000582a1a7b8} (b05434f7)
 - private final 'e' 'Lcom/mojang/serialization/Codec;' @28  a 'com/mojang/serialization/Codec$2'{0x0000000582a1a860} (b054350c)
 - private final 'b' 'I' @32  0
 - private final 'c' 'I' @36  15 (f)
 - private final 'a' 'Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;' @40  a 'com/google/common/collect/RegularImmutableSet'{0x0000000582a1a900} (b0543520)
RSP=0x00007fd840e35810 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fd870198a90
RBP=0x0000000580bbdc78 is an oop: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMapEntry
{0x0000000580bbdc78} - klass: 'com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMapEntry'
 - ---- fields (total size 3 words):
 - final 'key' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @12  a 'ddb'{0x0000000582a1a788} (b05434f1)
 - final 'value' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @16  a 'java/lang/Integer'{0x00000007ff86f510} = 0 (fff0dea2)
RSI=0x0000000582a1a788 is an oop: ddb
{0x0000000582a1a788} - klass: 'ddb'
 - ---- fields (total size 6 words):
 - private final 'a' 'Ljava/lang/Class;' @12  a 'java/lang/Class'{0x00000007ff701a98} = 'java/lang/Integer' (ffee0353)
 - private final 'b' 'Ljava/lang/String;' @16  "age"{0x0000000582ad36b0} (b055a6d6)
 - private 'c' 'Ljava/lang/Integer;' @20  a 'java/lang/Integer'{0x00000005841a8d60} = 1101196024 (b08351ac)
 - private final 'd' 'Lcom/mojang/serialization/Codec;' @24  a 'com/mojang/serialization/Codec$2'{0x0000000582a1a7b8} (b05434f7)
 - private final 'e' 'Lcom/mojang/serialization/Codec;' @28  a 'com/mojang/serialization/Codec$2'{0x0000000582a1a860} (b054350c)
 - private final 'b' 'I' @32  0
 - private final 'c' 'I' @36  15 (f)
 - private final 'a' 'Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;' @40  a 'com/google/common/collect/RegularImmutableSet'{0x0000000582a1a900} (b0543520)
RDI=0x0000000580bbdc90 is an oop: [Lcom.google.common.collect.ImmutableMapEntry;
{0x0000000580bbdc90} - klass: 'com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMapEntry'[]
 - length: 8
R8 =0x00000000bff0dea2 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000000f83c0674 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000800000000 is pointing into metadata
R11=2958308593 is a compressed pointer to object: ddb
{0x0000000582a1a788} - klass: 'ddb'
 - ---- fields (total size 6 words):
 - private final 'a' 'Ljava/lang/Class;' @12  a 'java/lang/Class'{0x00000007ff701a98} = 'java/lang/Integer' (ffee0353)
 - private final 'b' 'Ljava/lang/String;' @16  "age"{0x0000000582ad36b0} (b055a6d6)
 - private 'c' 'Ljava/lang/Integer;' @20  a 'java/lang/Integer'{0x00000005841a8d60} = 1101196024 (b08351ac)
 - private final 'd' 'Lcom/mojang/serialization/Codec;' @24  a 'com/mojang/serialization/Codec$2'{0x0000000582a1a7b8} (b05434f7)
 - private final 'e' 'Lcom/mojang/serialization/Codec;' @28  a 'com/mojang/serialization/Codec$2'{0x0000000582a1a860} (b054350c)
 - private final 'b' 'I' @32  0
 - private final 'c' 'I' @36  15 (f)
 - private final 'a' 'Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;' @40  a 'com/google/common/collect/RegularImmutableSet'{0x0000000582a1a900} (b0543520)
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13=0x00007fd840e358a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fd870198a90
R14=0x0 is NULL
R15=0x00007fd870198a90 is a thread
```